# angular.jsと競合関係にあるフレームワーク

Tags: javascript

フロントエンドの勉強をしようと思っていますが、angular.jsを学ぶか、他のものを学ぶか迷っています。
angular.jsと競合関係にあるフレームワークと、できればそのメリットや特徴などを教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: 質問の投稿ありがとうございます。現時点でマイナス票が多く付いていますが、[質問の範囲が広すぎ](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)て解決・回答しにくいためではないかと思います。「仮想DOMはどういう問題を解決する技術か？」などのように範囲を絞るか、もし業務上直面している問題があれば、その解決したい内容を詳しく共有するとよいかと思います。(質問は後から[edit]できます。) それまで質問を一旦保留 (改善待ち) 状態にします。

Answer (score 2):

ここにまとまっていると思われるURLを幾つか記載します。

- [いかにして我々はフロントエンドに秩序をもたらそうとしてきたか](https://gist.github.com/mizchi/9635965)
- [JavaScript フレームワーク - ペパボのフロントエンドスタンダード](http://pepabo.github.io/docs/frontend/standard/javascript-framework.html)
- [【JavaScript】なんとか.jsのお話(backbone.js、angular.js、node.js、alt.js、unserscore.js、prototype.js....etc)](http://yyyank.blogspot.jp/2014/08/jsbackbonejsangularjsnodejsaltjsunsersc.html)